# Format Query Results using Cross join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

so I'm still new to cross joins, I very rarely use them. I was able to find an answer to the first part of my problem, but not the second.

I've got the results to output in the layout that I want, here are the results

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| Full Name | cert_type |       expiration        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| Jane Doe  |         1 | 2015-09-26 00:00:00.000 |
| Jane Doe  |         2 | 2015-04-21 00:00:00.000 |
| Jane Doe  |         3 | 2015-12-16 00:00:00.000 |
| John Doe  |         1 | 2016-10-06 00:00:00.000 |
| John Doe  |         2 | 2015-04-19 00:00:00.000 |
| John Doe  |         3 | 2011-04-12 00:00:00.000 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Here is my query as well:

```
SELECT
    [Full Name], 
    cert_type = X.which,
    expiration  =
        CASE X.which
        WHEN '1' THEN [License Exp Date]
        WHEN '2' THEN [Med Cert Exp Date]
        WHEN '3' THEN [Annual MVR Review Due]
        END
FROM employee_data.dbo.EmployeeDataBase
CROSS JOIN (SELECT '1' UNION ALL SELECT '2' UNION ALL SELECT '3') X (which)
WHERE [License Exp Date] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())
OR [Med Cert Exp Date] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())
OR [Annual MVR Review Due] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())
AND [Termination Date] IS NULL
```

As you can see even with the `WHERE` clause still in place, it's pulling every date, and I"m only wanting the dates that are within the given ranges inside the `WHERE` clause. I also want the dates to output like they would if I set them to 
`OUTPUT(VARCHAR(10), date, 101)`

If there are further questions please let me know, I will keep working over here. Thank you for all the help I receive!

Comment: Are you wanting to have NULL when the given columns value it outside your date range? If so, move that condition to your case expression. As for outputting formatted dates, I would highly recommend you leave the formatting to the front end and not do it in sql.

Comment: No, I only want the query to select the dates, that are within the range. If they are null, or out of the range, then I don't want to select them.

Comment: Your where predicates work on the entire row so if ANY of the dates are within the range it will be in your resultset. One way you could deal with this is to have your above query be a cte and then select from the cte with your above where predicates. That would then let you exclude each row.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the names, not that it matters, but I see your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. You should get in the habit of using the name of the datepart instead of the abbreviation. They are difficult to remember and using the name is very clear.

```
with MyCTE as
(
    SELECT
        [Full Name], 
        cert_type = X.which,
        expiration  =
            CASE X.which
            WHEN '1' THEN [License Exp Date]
            WHEN '2' THEN [Med Cert Exp Date]
            WHEN '3' THEN [Annual MVR Review Due]
            END
    FROM employee_data.dbo.EmployeeDataBase
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT '1' UNION ALL SELECT '2' UNION ALL SELECT '3') X (which)
    WHERE [License Exp Date] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())
    OR [Med Cert Exp Date] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())
    OR [Annual MVR Review Due] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())
    AND [Termination Date] IS NULL
)

select *
from MyCTE
where expiration BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE())
```

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)